# Setting up a gaming console with a chromebook, ps3 controller issues

Tags: ps3, controllers, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up my new chromebook as a steam console, but having trouble getting it to recognize ps3 controllers.

Using Ubuntu, Steam runs quite well, since I'm lucky enough to have a chromebook pixel. I'm using the crouton shell script to dual boot, but that means I'm stuck on the 3.8 version of the Linux kernel for now.

I have tried a number of different drivers and scripts, including the popular xboxdrv which I had success with on previous computers, but none on this one.

Anyone try this before?

Comment: Minor update: updated to chrome os beta channel thinking that would update ubuntu's kernel, but the kernel stayed the same. However, ubuntu is now recognizing the ps3 controller as a "mouse", and the select button as left click.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I did two things, and I think both were necessary. Installed this for better controller support, https://launchpad.net/~mdeslaur/+archive/ubuntu/steamos

and ran the games with sudo. Hopefully it becomes a smoother process over time with software updates, but for now this is a decent solution.